# Aspect ratio of image view is not the same on iPad as on iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to make a Connect Four game and everything is working fine, except that the aspect ratio of my board is differing when on iPad vs. when on iPhone and I can't seem to figure out the problem. This is causing issues for me because I rely on the aspect ratio to be able to calculate the position of the pieces as I am dropping them onto the board.

I made a basic example of the problem and the code is the following

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    let bottomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    bottomView.backgroundColor = .red
    bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bottomView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor),
        bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor),
        bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor),
        bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120)
    ])

    let image = UIImage(named: "Frontground")
    imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(imageView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor),
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor),
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 329/389),
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.topAnchor, constant: -32)
    ])
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let desiredAspectRatio = CGFloat(CGFloat(389)/CGFloat(329))
    let actualAspectRatio = imageView.frame.size.width/imageView.frame.size.height

    print("Desired Aspect Ratio is \(desiredAspectRatio), actual Aspect ratio is \(actualAspectRatio)")
}
```

The image I am using has a width of 389 and a height of 329 and I want to maintain that relationship across all devices.

The aspect Ratio on the iPad is not THAT far off, but it's enough for it to make pieces end up not fitting in the holes precisely. Everything works fine on the iPhone versions though, even though my aspect ratio isn't precise, maybe because the screen is smaller the issues are not as noticeable.

Here is an example of the image of I used.

[image: Sample Image]

When i run on an iPhone I get:
Desired Aspect Ratio is 1.182370820668693, actual Aspect ratio is 1.1828571428571428

When I run on an iPad I get: 
Desired Aspect Ratio is 1.182370820668693, actual Aspect ratio is 1.1824817518248176

Is there anyway for me to get the exact aspect ratio that I want?

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Alan

Comment: Are you seeing any NSLayoutConstraint errors while running this?   Also, you may want to try casting `329/389` when you're defining the constant. to avoid any implicit type casting issues.   You could put in `CGFloat(0.8457583547557841)` as the constant as well to rule out issues there.

Comment: Since you are using the aspect ratio to do calculations, why not just accept the real aspect ratio and do the calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `UIKit` can't draw on partial pixels.

Using your constraints on various devices, the Widths will be round numbers, but the calculated Heights will not... so auto-layout will adjust.

On these devices we get:

```
Ratio: 329.0 / 389.0 = 0.8457583547557841

iPad Pro 12.9
actual w: 1024.0 * 0.8457583547557841 = 866.0565552699229 ... but actual h: 866.0

iPad Pro 9.7
actual w:  768.0 * 0.8457583547557841 = 649.5424164524422 ... but actual h: 649.5

iPhone 8
actual w:  375.0 * 0.8457583547557841 = 317.15938303341903 ... but actual h: 317.0

iPhone 11
actual w:  414.0 * 0.8457583547557841 = 350.14395886889463 ... but actual h: 350.0
```

So your *Actual Aspect Ratio* on different sizes will ***not*** be exactly the same.

To get pixel-perfect alignments, you'll need to account for that.

Also note that **Points** are not equal to **Pixels**. On `2x` screen scale devices, frame values can be rounded to 1/2 points, so you may get a height such as `649.5` points.

On `3x` screen scale devices, frame values can be rounded to 1/3 points, so you may get a height of `649.6666667` points.